# How to get JQuery-UI autocomplete to submit on pressing enter while using categories from remote source?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm using the following boiler plate code from the jqueryui site:
http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories
http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote

```
$.widget("custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _create: function() {
        this._super();
        this.widget().menu("option", "items", "> :not(.ui-autocomplete-category)");
    },
    _renderMenu: function(ul, items) {
        var that = this,
            currentCategory = "";
        $.each(items, function(index, item) {
            var li;
            if (item.category != currentCategory) {
                ul.append("<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>");
                currentCategory = item.category;
            }
            li = that._renderItemData(ul, item);
            if (item.category) {
                li.attr("aria-label", item.category + " : " + item.label);
            }
        });
    },
});

$(function() {

    $("#search").catcomplete({
        delay: 0,
        source: "search",
        select: function(event, ui) {
            ajax.get("/displayInfo", {
                a: ui.item.value
            }, displayInfo, true);
        }
    });
});
```

But how do I get the input trigger "select" even a user just presses enter ? Right now if you just press enter (without selecting anything from the drop down), the drop down disappears and nothing happens. But I wan't it to send whatever is in the drop down (even if it doesn't match) to /displayInfo.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: When the suggestions list is [open](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-open), `ui` argument is empty... I don't think this is gonna be easy, you might want to raise a feature request @ [bugs.jqueryui.com](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/)

Comment: I imagine this is a very common use case, and I thought there must be someone else who already has this requirement, or figured out a workaround..

Comment: Well it sounds like a common use case to me as well, which is why I suggested raising a feature request.. :)

Answer (score 0):

When auto complete search appears use arrow keys and press enters it will auto papulate the value to the textbox.
OR
You can use onkeyup or onkeypress events then find event.keycode for Enter then use functionality.

Comment: That would kill the experience for the end user.